# Bootstrap customize collapse navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is this possible to customize the content of the collapsed navbar?

Exemple:

I have in my top nav bar : Login / Register

I have in a column of my website (non navbar) Categories: Electronic, Sports, Home.

Would it be possible to have all these link collapsed into a customize navbar?

Login
Register
Categories
  Electronic
  Sports
  Home

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can understand from your problem you want to show these links when you have a collapsed navbar. Otherwise not to display them- **Login Register Categories Electronic Sports Home** It will show categories in collapsed mode and only show brandname on large and medium displays.

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active hidden-md hidden-lg"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            
            <li class="hidden-md hidden-lg"><a href="#">Electronics</a></li>
            <li class="hidden-md hidden-lg"><a href="#"></a>Sports</li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-md hidden-lg ">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot!
I will upvote as soon as I get back to 15.

Comment: @QuentinDel If this is what are you looking for accept as answer.